# mysqli_fetch_array Returning One Row Within TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

The code below shows a php query I am trying to execute within TCPDF.  However the query I am running only seems to display one row from the database when there are 3 results that should be returned in the table.  Having looked at numerous examples I understand that the line:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Is the main reason for only returning one row.  Here is the bulk of the code to return the Quantity, Description, Unit Price and Line Price.  I just need each row to sit underneath each other.  Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result5 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_sale_basket WHERE ORDER_ID=$ID");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result5))
  {
  $quantity = $row["QUANTITY"];
  $description = $row["NAME"];
  $unitprice = $row["PRICE"];
  $lineprice = $row["PRICE"]*$row["QUANTITY"];
  }

$tbl_header = '<table style="width: 650px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">';
$tbl_footer = '</table>';
$tbl = '';

// foreach item in your array...
$tbl .= '
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50px; text-align: left;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.$quantity.'</p></td>
        <td style="width: 400px;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.$description.'</p></td>
        <td style="width: 125px;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.$unitprice.'</p></td>
        <td style="width: 75px; text-align:right;" align="right"><p style="color:#808080;">'.$lineprice.'</p></td>
    </tr>
';

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: your $tbl .= ''; code should be in while loop

Comment: I have tried that to no avail.. Could you illustrate what you mean?

Comment: Sorry sorted it, understood what you meant after a little thinking.  The closing bracket for the while is now at the end.  Thanks